# pascal case custom html tag in Quill js

Tags: reactjs, text-editor, quill, react-quill

I need to have a custom HTML tag in Quill js that is in Pascal case.
But at the time of insertion, it becomes a lowercase.

for instance:

```
class MyCustomDataTag extends Embed {
  static create(param) {
    const node = super. Create(param)
    node.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration: underline;background-color : lightblue;')
    node.setAttribute('field', param.value)
    node.innerHTML = param.text
    return node
  }
}

MyCustomDataTag.blotName = 'Data'
MyCustomDataTag.tagName = 'Data'
Quill.register({
  'formats/Data': MyCustomDataTag
})
```

In the example above, I need `<Data></Data>`, but I see `<data></data>`.